# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setTabColor')

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, openai-api, google-apps-script-api

I have minimal knowledge about coding or javascript but I tried to generate a code with ChatGPT but when I try to run it in google apps script it gives me an error saying: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'setTabColor')

The script it supposed to create a google sheets for me.
This is the script I am trying to run:

```js
function createTaskTracker() {
  // Create a new Google Sheets document
  var sheetName = "Task Tracker";
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(sheetName);

  // Set up the tabs for the document
  var tabs = ["Overall", "Work", "Social Media", "Workout", "Freetime", "Long-Term         Progress"];
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    var tabName = tabs[i];
    var sheet = spreadsheet.insertSheet(tabName);
  }

  // Set the tab colors to match the categories
  var colors = ["#ffffff", "#00ff00", "#0000ff", "#ffff00", "#ff0000"];
  var categoryTabs = ["Work", "Sports/Training", "Freetime", "Social Media"];
  for (var i = 0; i < categoryTabs.length; i++) {
    var categoryTab = categoryTabs[i];
    var colorIndex = i + 1;
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(categoryTab);
    var color = colors[colorIndex];
    sheet.setTabColor(color);
  }

  // Set up the column headers for each tab
  var headers = ["Task", "Routine", "Time Spent", "Status", "Progress"];
  var tabsWithHeaders = ["Work", "Sports/Training", "Freetime", "Social Media"];
  for (var i = 0; i < tabsWithHeaders.length; i++) {
    var tabName = tabsWithHeaders[i];
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(tabName);
    sheet.appendRow(headers);
  }

  // Freeze the first row on each tab
  for (var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
    var tabName = tabs[i];
    var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(tabName);
    sheet.setFrozenRows(1);
  }

  // Rename the default sheet to "Settings"
  var defaultSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  defaultSheet.setName("Settings");

  // Add a message to the main tab
  var mainTab = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Overall");
  mainTab.getRange("A1").setValue("Welcome to your Task Tracker!");
}
```

Since I have minimal knowledge about scripts I really had no solution or didn´t find a direct answer from a google search.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when setting the tab colors, you have sheet name that doesn't exist in your current tabs/sheet names.

Initially, the tabs are set as:

```
var tabs = ["Overall", "Work", "Social Media", "Workout", "Freetime", "Long-Term Progress"];
```

The ones set to be colored are:

```
var categoryTabs = ["Work", "Sports/Training", "Freetime", "Social Media"];
```

Because `Sports/Training` doesn't exist, when it is called to have it's tab colored, it is not found (`null`).

**Try this:**

```
function createTaskTracker() {

  const Spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create(`Task Tracker`)

  const headers = ["Task", "Routine", "Time Spent", "Status", "Progress"]

  const tabs = [

    {
      Title: `Overall`,
      TabColor: `#ffffff`,
      HasHeaders: false
    },
    {
      Title: `Work`,
      TabColor: `#00ff00`,
      HasHeaders: true
    },
    {
      Title: `Social Media`,
      TabColor: `#ff0000`,
      HasHeaders: true
    },
    {
      Title: `Workout`,
      TabColor: `#0000ff`,
      HasHeaders: true
    },
    {
      Title: `Freetime`,
      TabColor: `#ffff00`,
      HasHeaders: true
    },
    {
      Title: `Long-Term Progress`,
      TabColor: `#ffffff`,
      HasHeaders: true
    },

  ]

  tabs.forEach(tab => {

    const newTab = Spreadsheet.insertSheet()
    newTab.setName(tab.Title)
    newTab.setTabColor(tab.TabColor)

    if (tab.HasHeaders) {
      newTab.appendRow(headers)
      newTab.setFrozenRows(1)
    }

  })

  Spreadsheet.deleteSheet(Spreadsheet.getSheetByName(`Sheet1`))

}
```